# Can you use php without downloading it?

Tags: php

I am trying to use php on my website but I am wondering if I could use it without downloading it. I've already surfed the internet for a answer, but none of them had a clear answer. Please help!

Comment: If you have a Mac: http://php.net/manual/en/install.macosx.bundled.php

Comment: Well, to run PHP it needs to be installed. Unless you have some kind of os distribution that already has it installed, you need to download it. Not sure what your question is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: can i chew without my teeth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start using PHP, you can:

Find a web host with PHP and MySQL support OR
Install a web server on your own PC, and then install PHP and MySQL

If your server has activated support for PHP you do not need to do anything.

Just create some .php files, place them in your web directory, and the server will automatically parse them for you.

You do not need to compile anything or install any extra tools.

Because PHP is free, most web hosts offer PHP support.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_install.asp

Comment: So there is no way of using it without downloading?

Comment: Downloading it not enough, you will need to install it. Unless your server already has it installed.. It's not some library that you can just point to and have it included in your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: You are welcome! If you are new to PHP, I suggest reading up on it. w3schools is a great resource for basic understanding of languages. Good Luck!

Comment: W3schools is an awful resource for anything. http://www.phptherightway.com/